# GridView rows some times overlaps

Tags: android, gridview

I have a GridView which is using to show a sentence ( as an example: "all over again" can be a sentence here.)

My problem is sometimes second row overlaps the first row. I do not understand why. Here are some pictures show my problem.

[image]

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/sol_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
        android:numColumns="8"
        android:verticalSpacing="35dp" />
```

This is parts of my code:

```
GridView solutionGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sol_1);
final AlphabetCharAdapter solutionCharAdapter = new AlphabetCharAdapter(getApplicationContext(), solutionChars);
solutionGrid.setAdapter(solutionCharAdapter);
```

And this is my Adapter class:

```
public class AlphabetCharAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private AlphabetChar[] alphabetCharList;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public AlphabetCharAdapter(Context applicationContext, AlphabetChar[] alphabetCharList) {
    this.alphabetCharList = alphabetCharList;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return alphabetCharList.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_charachters, parent, false); // inflate the layout
    }
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.simple_character); // get the reference of ImageView
    if (alphabetCharList[i].getCharacter() == ' ') {
        iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        iv.setImageResource(charToImageConverter.getID(alphabetCharList[i].getCharacter(), view)); // set logo images
    }
    return view;
}
```

I tested "android:verticalSpacing" and increased that in my xml file. It gets better, but the problem is, whatever I increase verticalSpacing to fix upper image overlapping, the below image verticalSpace becomes larger. Is there any solution for this problem? I do not know why this overlapping is happening in upper image!

Thanks!

Comment: Provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).